# c++ error no instance of constructor

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and trying just to return values passed through the constructor, I am not sure what I have done wrong on the below code it keeps giving me an error: `no instance of constructor..matches`, `cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const char [5]' to 'int'`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class TestClass{
    string a;
    string b;
    int x;
public:
    TestClass(string m, string n, int y){
        this->a = m;
        this->b = n;
        this->x = y;
    }
    int test(){
        return this->x;
    }
};

int main(){
    TestClass *a = new TestClass("test1","test2","9999");
    cout<<a->test()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: the third parameter is an int, "9999" is not an int, or convertible to one.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You gave it an array and it wanted an `int`. By the way, get rid of that pointer and just do `TestClass a(...);` You can also get rid of the `this->` everywhere, as well as the semicolons after the includes.

Comment: BTW: If you allocate an object, you should also deallocate it. To avoid errors, use smart-pointers like `std::unique_ptr`. Even better: Keep it on the stack and avoid the heap alltogether. You might also take a look at ctor-init-lists, and search for "Avoiding `using namespace std;`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the number 9999 as `"9999"` -- the quotes around it denote it is a string. Simply pass it as `9999`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your third parameter from "9999" to 9999. The quotes say you're treating it as a string when in fact the constructor is expecting an `int`.

Comment: Well, treating it as a string (the concept), not a `string` (the C++ type `std::string`). Character literals have the type `const char [n]`, which is not the same thing as `std::string`.